# How to retrieve all the details and properties of an image in JavaScript/ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, location

I am trying to fetch all the details of an image using JavaScript like we can see the details in windows by going to the properties.
For an instance, below are the details of an image, is there any way to get all those details via javaScript as well?

[image]

[image]

[image]

My Main Motive is to fetch max possible details especially the GPS coordinates using JavaScript.
Can someone please assist in this case as I did some research as well but didn't got any useful resources as of now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying getting of these information from an image, it's not trivial / easy, you should process the image file, you you can have some alternatives that you could take.

1. Your backend service can retrieve that information for you when making an api call.
2. If you really want to get this information in a browser env, so you should extract the exif data from an image, you could try this package called [exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) that actually do that thing.

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to share any relevant sources regarding how we can retrieve information using backend services ?

Comment: @GursimranSingh don't worry ask whatever you need, but in case you want to get these information into the backend I, if you are using nodejs, I highly recommend you looking for a kind of lib as I mentioned before in the answer, you can take a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif-reader